# Troubleshooting ERROR: extra data after last expected column

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

I'm trying to add CSV data to my Postgres table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Review (
 review_id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL,
 product_id_Metadata INTEGER,
 date DATE,
 summary VARCHAR(255),
 body VARCHAR(500),
 rating INTEGER,
 recommend BOOLEAN,
 reported BOOLEAN
 reviewer_name VARCHAR(50),
 reviewer_email VARCHAR(50),
 response VARCHAR(255),
 helpfulness INTEGER,
 FOREIGN KEY product_id(product_id) REFERENCES Metadata(product_id)
);
```

Running the CMD:

`COPY review (product_id_Metadata, summary, body, rating, recommend, reported, reviewer_name, reviewer_email, response, helpfulness) FROM '/Users/luke82601/Desktop/csv/reviews.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;`

The CSV file has the same number of columns as my Postgres table, so I'm not sure why this error occurs

Comment: But the column DATE is not in the copy column list.  If your columns in the CSV matches the table that means the CSV does not match the specified column list. Try either adding date to the copy list, or removing it from the CSV.

Comment: Oh geez, simple mistakes, they're killers. Thanks for that, I added it and it worked like gangbusters